# run application that uses setup.py file

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I have the application that uses `setup.py` with entry point like this

```
  entry_points={
      'console_scripts': [
          'service = service.main:main',
      ]
  }
```

When building `whl` package using `setup.py` file, I can install it and run the application just fine using the application name.

The project itself is organized in a way that I have `src` folder with the source code.

```
src/
    service/
       main.py
```

But I need to deploy it to CloudFoundry. I thought to specify the start command in a manifest file.

```
applications:
 - buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack#v1.7.15
   disk_quota: 2G
   command: python setup.py ???
```

But how to run it without creating and then installing a package? Because running it like `python src/service/main.py` doesn't work, so I presume I need to execute it differently or something.

Comment: Have you tried `python setup.py develop` and then invoke the result script using `service`

Comment: You mean in two commands?

Comment: You mean in two commands?

Comment: yes, something like `python setup.py develop && service ....`

Comment: @Chase it seems to be working locally, but when executing in CF it fails with "bash: service command not found" despite having the same logs locally and in cloud

Comment: try to do activate a virtual env first

Comment: Not 100% sure this will work for your app, but try putting `-e .` (or something like that) in your `requirements.txt` file. The `-e` flag will go through to pip and allow you to install a local package, i.e. your source code. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format. The Python buildpack will then install everything in requirements.txt when it runs, so you should then be able to just run your service just using the app name like you do locally.

Comment: @DanielMikusa the problem is that it seems the buildpack itself doesn't contain `pip`.  When I put `pip list` in `command` it tells me that `pip command not found`

Comment: The buildpack should definitely include `pip`. I'm not 100% sure it will be available at runtime though, I'd have to double check. The command you set will be executed at runtime, not when the buildpack runs. If you add what I suggested to requirements.txt, the buildpack should execute pip for you and install everything in that file.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I looked into buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/releases and it has conda, pipenv, pip-pop but no pip

Comment: @lapots - I'm pretty sure that the buildpack installs a version of Python that includes pip. I know it's there though, use it often. Glad you found a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I dropped `setup.py` altogether, adjusted project structure and created `__main__.py` file.

```
service\
    __main__.py
    ....
```

Then I set `command: python -m service` and that at least started the application.